# How to insert html element just before body closing tag as last loading

Tags: javascript

I got a page that loads several add-ons and I need to insert html element (script) just before body closing tag (</ body>) **as last loading**. I tried some javascript methods such as appendChild and insertAdjacentElement, but none seem to work because of loading other scripts.

What I have done so far and didn't work:

**Using appendChild or insertAdjacentElement got same result:**

```
var myscript = document.createElement('script');
myscript.setAttribute('src','https://xxxxx/myscript.min.js');
myscript.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(myscript);  or  document.body.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', myscript);
```

**Result:**

```
<body>
   <element1>
   <element2>
   *<myscript> <--- inserted here*
   <element3>
   <element4>
   <element5>
   <element6>
   <element7>
</body>
```

**Expected result:**

```
<body>
   <element1>
   <element2>
   <element3>
   <element4>
   <element5>
   <element6>
   <element7>
   *<myscript> <--- insert here*
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried `myscript.defer = true;` ?

Comment: I tried as well but it stays on same position.

Comment: is it possible the elements that exist after `<myscript>` are created as a result of executing that script? why do you believe the script HAS to be last?

Comment: It has to be the last because I am using bootstrap, and in my case, the script will only work if the last one (i have already tested).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the javascript code might be executed before the html document is fully loaded. To avoid this place your javascript code inside a DOMContentLoaded to make sure the code runs after the DOM is fully loaded:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var myscript = document.createElement('myscript');
   myscript.setAttribute('src','https://xxxxx/myscript.min.js');
   myscript.async = true;
   document.body.appendChild(myscript);
});
```

Comment: That was a good option, it seems to load as last one, but in my case should be after the iframe (just checked now). Take a look: https://imgur.com/a/Q9RhO0F

Comment: I marked yours as correct answer because it was really last script. But in my case I had to find last child, got with this code: var last = document.querySelector('body:last-child'); / last.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', script);

Answer (score 0):

seems to be working for me with append

[image: console shows the script element last of the body]